# Is it possible to install flash firmware update without having access to OSX?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, install, firmware

So I erased my HD and wanted to install Mac OSX Mavericks on my MacBook Air mid 2012 model and after I booted from the USB and was about to install Mavericks the damn thing tells me it can't do so because I first need to install some MacBook Air Flash Storage Firmware Update 1.1 before I can install Mavericks.

Obviously I can't do that since I no longer have any OSX installed and do not really want to download and install Mountain Lion just to install this update.

Is there a way to run this flash firmware update from the EFI boot/setup section ? Perhaps there's a way to suppress this check for the 'flash firmware' update ?

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this is directly possible. Maybe via the repair partition (press and hold <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> after the startup chime) of Os X - assuming that you do not have deleted it to and used Mountain Lion or Lion prior on the Macbook.

What should work but take some time to do so is to install your old operating system and  either than download the flash update and install it and install a „clean“ install of Mavericks after this procedure or just install Mavericks right on top of it via the Mac Appstore.

Answer (score 0):

""press and hold CMD+r after the startup chime) of Os X - assuming that you do not have deleted it to and used Mountain Lion or Lion prior on the Macbook"".
If this is not possible, you may try the same with CMD+R+Alt(option), in which case it reaches the R partition in internet. But I doubt it, although you never know.

Answer (score 0):

Not easily. Apple's firmware updater runs on top of OS X.  Your best bet would be to install a new copy of OS X onto a USB drive and run the firmware updateer from there if you don't want to touch the internal storage.